# how to store the modified date of multiple files in an array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm new to shell scrip programming and currently have a problem with arrays and finding multiple files. Here's my code:

```
todate=$(date -d 2016-02-03 +"%Y%m%d")  
mod=$(date -r case +"%Y%m%d")

if [ $mod -ge $todate ]; 
then
    echo 'yes';
else
    echo 'no';
fi
```

In this piece of codes, I find the modified date of the file named case then compare it to the variable $todate. Now how can I find the modified dates of all the files from a directory and store them in an array so I can compare each date to $todate?

Comment: Do you know "loops"? -- Not those from a roller coaster.

Comment: yes I do. I'm trying to store all the dates to an array then use loops to compare each date to the given date.

Comment: duplicate http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141148/store-all-dates-in-a-given-date-range-into-a-variable

Comment: what is the ultimate problem? unix `find` command can most probably do that already without you having to script it.

Comment: yeah but my professor doesn't allow us to use any built in function like 'find'

Comment: From your options to `date`, I infer that you're running Linux, despite the lack of tag. So I'll point out that tools like `date` and `stat` are NOT part of bash, and they function differently in Linux than they do in other environments, notably OS X and other BSD-based operating systems. If your professor wants you to avoid using tools that are external to the shell, then `date` and even `ls` are off limits.  Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
  ls -l --full-time | tr -s " " | cut -f6 -d " "| sort | uniq | awk
 'BEGIN{"date +%Y-%m-%d"|getline today} length > 1 && $0 !~ today' >
 file
```

**file** will have the dates in it

**ls -l --full-time** : gives list of date in full-format

**tr -s " "** : squeezes extra spaces

**cut -f6 -d " "** : get the 6th column value, which is the modified date.

**sort & uniq** : sorts the records and uniq values are obtained

**awk 'BEGIN{ "date +%Y-%m-%d"|getline today} length > 1 && $0 !~ today'**: checks if not empty or current date is present, then write to file

Comment: [Parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is always a bad idea. Also, no operating system is specified in the question, but you are using OS-specific options on the `ls` command.